# I get error 404 not found in html img in vue

Tags: webpack, vuejs3

Why webpack 5 and vue 3 dont surch images, even though I chose the right.

When i use webpack 4 images conver to base64, but when i update plugins to new version i get error.

```
   <img src="/src/assets/logo.png"</a>--> error
 <img src="@/assets/logo.png" </a> --> error
```

in css file work good (convert to base64)
If i do this, it works

```
:src="require('@/assets/images/logo.png')"
```

This is path images:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty73O.png)

This is error 404:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9KF.png)

When i get image to vue component :

```
 import MyImage from '@/assets/logo.png'
```

i get correct base64 image

package :

```
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --coverage",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "clean": "rm -rf node_modules target",
    "i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src \"./src/**/*.?(js|vue)\" --locales \"./src/locales/**/*.json\"",
    "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit && vue-cli-service test:e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.4",
    "axios": "0.21.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
    "core-js": "3.20.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "paginationjs": "^2.1.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "properties-to-json": "^0.2.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "summernote": "^0.8.18",
    "summernote-cleaner": "^1.0.0",
    "v-pagination-3": "^0.1.7",
    "vee-validate": "^4.5.10",
    "vue": "3.2.31",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.0",
    "vue-router": "4.0.11",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.2",
    "vue3-summernote-editor": "^1.0.2",
    "vuejs-paginate-next": "^1.0.2",
    "vuetify": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "vuex": "4.0.2",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
    "@types/webfontloader": "^1.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.18.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "3.2.11",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "9.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "2.0.0-rc.14",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "chromedriver": "96.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "8.6.0",
    "geckodriver": "2.0.4",
    "node-sass": "6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.38.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.5.5",
    "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "~2.3.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.8",
    "vue-jest": "5.0.0-alpha.10",
    "vuetify-loader": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  }
```

Vue config:

```
// vue.config.js
// const path = require('path')
module.exports = {

  // proxy all webpack dev-server requests starting with /api
  // to our Spring Boot backend (localhost:8098) using http-proxy-middleware
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy
  configureWebpack: {


      resolve: {
      alias: {
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: "jquery",
        jquery: "jquery",
      }
    }
  },
  
  devServer: {


    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8098', // this configuration needs to correspond to the Spring Boot backends' application.properties server.port
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },

  // Change build paths to make them Maven compatible
  // see https://cli.vuejs.org/config/
  outputDir: 'target/dist',

  assetsDir: 'static',

  pluginOptions: {
    i18n: {
      locale: 'ru',
      fallbackLocale: 'en',
      localeDir: 'locales',
      enableLegacy: false,
      runtimeOnly: false,
      compositionOnly: false,
      fullInstall: true
    },
    vuetify: {
            // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vuetify-loader
        }
  }
};
```

.eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {

    root: true,
    env: {
        node: true
    },
    'extends': [
        'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
        'eslint:recommended',
        '@vue/typescript/recommended'
    ],
    parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: 2020,
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'
    },
    rules: {
        'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
        'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
        'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
        "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": [
            "error",
            {
                "allowDestructuring": false, // Allow `const { props, state } = this`; false by default
                "allowedNames":  ["vm","self","$this"] // Allow `const vm= this`; `[]` by default
            }
        ]
    },

    overrides: [
      {
        files: [
          '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
          '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
        ],
        env: {
          jest: true
        }
      },
      {
        files: [
          '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
          '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
        ],
        env: {
          jest: true
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

When i can do to fix errors?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a webpack issue where your image files are not bundled correctly. Try using the require() method inside src for you images.
Example:

```
<img :src="require('@/assets/images/logo.png')">
```

This ensures that the files are bundled.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a basepath in the mFE "server" worked for me.

```
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: 'esnext' //browsers can handle the latest ES features
  },
  base: 'http://localhost:5002/'
  ,
  plugins: [vue(),
    federation({
      name: 'otherRemote',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      // Modules to expose
      exposes: {
          './NewComponent': './src/components/NewComponent.vue',
      },
      shared: ['vue']
  })],
})
```

And in the template I had

```
<template>
  <div class="text">
    <img
      src="../../assets/ugly.jpg"
      alt="Official logo"
      style="max-width: 200px; width: 100%; height: 300px"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```